# Filling in Pandas DataFrame missing data based on mulit-column GroupBy

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset that I am trying to fill in blank cells. I am doing this by grouping (using `groupby`) the data on two of the columns and then propagating non-NaN (i.e. non-blank) data forward (`ffill`) and backward (`bfill`) within those groups. For some reason, rows that should be in separate groups are being filled when they shouldn't be. For example, in column "B", row "d" shouldn't be changed because it should be in its own group with no other rows to take data from. Same thing for "g". Yet, both these rows are filled in based on the data around them. Why is that and how can I get my desired result?

Code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({"A": [1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 6, 6],
                   "B": ['a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'd', 'c', 'e', 'e', 'g', 'h', 'h'],
                   "C": [5.0, np.nan, 4.0, 4.0, np.nan, 9.0, np.nan, np.nan, 9.0, 8.0, np.nan, 2.0, np.nan, 3.0],
                   "D": [1.0, 1.0, np.nan, 2.0, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 3.0, 2.0, np.nan, 9.0, np.nan, 3.0],
                   "E": [np.nan, 6.0, np.nan, 3.0, np.nan, np.nan, 7.0, np.nan, 7.0, 2.0, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 0.0]})

cols_to_groupby = ["A", "B"]
cols_to_fill = ["C", "D", "E"]

df[cols_to_fill] = df[cols_to_fill + cols_to_groupby].groupby(cols_to_groupby).ffill().bfill()
```

Sample dataset:

```
A B   C   D   E
1 a 5.0 1.0 NaN
1 a NaN 1.0 6.0
2 b 4.0 NaN NaN
2 b 4.0 2.0 3.0
2 b NaN NaN NaN
3 c 9.0 NaN NaN
3 c NaN NaN 7.0
3 d NaN NaN NaN
3 c 9.0 3.0 7.0
4 e 8.0 2.0 2.0
4 e NaN NaN NaN
5 g 2.0 9.0 NaN
6 h NaN NaN NaN
6 h 3.0 3.0 0.0
```

Expected outcome:

```
A B   C   D   E
1 a 5.0 1.0 6.0
1 a 5.0 1.0 6.0
2 b 4.0 2.0 3.0
2 b 4.0 2.0 3.0
2 b 4.0 2.0 3.0
3 c 9.0 3.0 7.0
3 c 9.0 3.0 7.0
3 d NaN NaN NaN
3 c 9.0 3.0 7.0
4 e 8.0 2.0 2.0
4 e 8.0 2.0 2.0
5 g 2.0 9.0 NaN
6 h 3.0 3.0 0.0
6 h 3.0 3.0 0.0
```

Actual outcome:

```
A B   C   D   E
1 a 5.0 1.0 6.0
1 a 5.0 1.0 6.0
2 b 4.0 2.0 3.0
2 b 4.0 2.0 3.0
2 b 4.0 2.0 3.0
3 c 9.0 3.0 7.0
3 c 9.0 3.0 7.0
3 d 9.0 3.0 7.0
3 c 9.0 3.0 7.0
4 e 8.0 2.0 2.0
4 e 8.0 2.0 2.0
5 g 2.0 9.0 0.0
6 h 3.0 3.0 0.0
6 h 3.0 3.0 0.0
```

---

Edit:

The accepted solution works for this particular case, but does not work properly if any of the columns being grouped on are missing values. The best solution, as of now, can be found in the accepted answer in this post: [Pandas deleting cells when filling groups with NaN in groupby column](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71486722/12131013).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, it is necessary to use a lambda function to call `ffill` and `bfill` per groups:

```
df[cols_to_fill] = df.groupby(cols_to_groupby)[cols_to_fill].apply(lambda x: x.ffill().bfill())
```

Alternative:

```
df[cols_to_fill] = df.groupby(cols_to_groupby)[cols_to_fill].transform(lambda x: x.ffill().bfill())
```

---

```
print(df)
    A  B    C    D    E
0   1  a  5.0  1.0  6.0
1   1  a  5.0  1.0  6.0
2   2  b  4.0  2.0  3.0
3   2  b  4.0  2.0  3.0
4   2  b  4.0  2.0  3.0
5   3  c  9.0  3.0  7.0
6   3  c  9.0  3.0  7.0
7   3  d  NaN  NaN  NaN
8   3  c  9.0  3.0  7.0
9   4  e  8.0  2.0  2.0
10  4  e  8.0  2.0  2.0
11  5  g  2.0  9.0  NaN
12  6  h  3.0  3.0  0.0
13  6  h  3.0  3.0  0.0
```

Your solution is forward filling values per groups, but back filling values outside of the groups:

```
print(df[cols_to_fill + cols_to_groupby].groupby(cols_to_groupby).ffill())
      C    D    E
0   5.0  1.0  NaN
1   5.0  1.0  6.0
2   4.0  NaN  NaN
3   4.0  2.0  3.0
4   4.0  2.0  3.0
5   9.0  NaN  NaN
6   9.0  NaN  7.0
7   NaN  NaN  NaN
8   9.0  3.0  7.0
9   8.0  2.0  2.0
10  8.0  2.0  2.0
11  2.0  9.0  NaN
12  NaN  NaN  NaN
13  3.0  3.0  0.0
```

---

```
print(df[cols_to_fill + cols_to_groupby].groupby(cols_to_groupby).ffill().bfill())
      C    D    E
0   5.0  1.0  6.0
1   5.0  1.0  6.0
2   4.0  2.0  3.0
3   4.0  2.0  3.0
4   4.0  2.0  3.0
5   9.0  3.0  7.0
6   9.0  3.0  7.0
7   9.0  3.0  7.0
8   9.0  3.0  7.0
9   8.0  2.0  2.0
10  8.0  2.0  2.0
11  2.0  9.0  0.0
12  3.0  3.0  0.0
13  3.0  3.0  0.0
```

Comment: Thank you, I see what was wrong with my original code. But I still have a problem because although this works on my sample dataset, I am still not getting the desired results on my actual dataset. In fact, in my actual dataset, I get _more_ blank cells than I had before... I will try and create a smaller dataset that reproduces these results.

Comment: @jared - Is possible sorting first by `cols_to_groupby` for see groups in order? Like `df = df.sort_values(cols_to_groupby)`.

Comment: Interesting. I could try that, but I would need to revert the sort after filling. How might I go about that?

Comment: @jared - I think only for test ;)

Comment: I am now unsure I understand what you are recommending.

Comment: @jared - I try explain - If not working in real datait is data related problem. So is necessary investigate data, here groups. And for easy testing is best if groups rows are together, so I rccomeneded sorting for test.

Comment: Sorting the DataFrame before grouping did not change my results.

Comment: @jared - So solution working in this sample data and not in real data? Can you change sample data for get data asimilar in real?

Comment: I have located the cause of the error. Please see my new question https://stackoverflow.com/q/71486722/12131013